# how to check if value exists in database from textbox c#

Tags: c#, database

ok so i have a text box and a button where i will enter a number and press the button. I then want a message box to display if the value has been found or not.

I put all my functions in a model class then call them for the GUI part.
heres what i tried so the sql function (ticket is the name of the table and ID is the value im trying to find):

```
  public void rebateslip(int ticketID)
    {
        SqlCommand myCommand  = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM ticket WHERE ID = @ticketID", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ticketID);


    }
```

and than for the button event handler i have this:

```
 private void buttonPrintRebateSlip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if (textBoxRebateSlip = model.rebateslip(ticketID)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found ticket");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ticket not in database");
            }

    }
```

but it says ticketID does not exist

Comment: Is your code is compiling?

Comment: do you mean at compile time? If you don't have a `tickedID` declared in your class then it indeed doesn't exist in your `Click` function... Also, I don't think your if statement can compile, you're trying to assign a `void` type to a `TextBox` type...

Comment: btw you don't even execute your command (unless you didn't paste the entire code of your function here)

Comment: no the code is not compiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change your `model.rebateslip` method so that it return a `bool`, and execute your command, then it should look more or less like this: (don't have the SqlCommand methods in mind, nor the reader's ones, but according to my memory it looks like this)

```
public bool rebateslip(int ticketID)
{
    SqlCommand myCommand  = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM ticket WHERE ID = @ticketID", con);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticketID", ticketID);
    var reader = myCommand.Execute();
    return reader.HasRows;    
}
```

then you should do something like @Ezekiel said in his answer:

```
int id;
if (!int.TryParse(textBoxRebateSlip.Text, out id)) return;

if (model.rebateslip(id))
...
```

Comment: thanks this code works. but it only works once. if i try enter another number into the textbox i get the error there is already an open DataReader associated with Command which must be closed first

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter is named `ticketID`, not `ID`

So, you should change to:

```
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticketID", ticketID);
```

Comment: ID is what the row is called in database

Answer (score 0):

if (textBoxRebateSlip =**=** model.rebateslip(ticketID)

Comment: sorry but this can't work either since the return type of `model.rebateslip` is `void`, and also you'll be comparing the `TextBox` object

Answer (score 0):

The If statement is not correct, you are missing a closing paren and the comparison is not valid either. Use == for comparison. Furthermore, ticketID variable is not initialized anywhere. From your description it sounds like you are getting it from the textbox? If so it should be something like this:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxRebateSlip .Text);

if (model.rebateslip(ticketID) == id)
```

...

Another thing I noticed, you are not executing the sql command anywhere?

Also, the rebateslip method has return type void, so it will not work.

With all these errors, this code would not even compile.

Comment: no ticketId is the value in the database. the text from the textbox is being compared to ticketID