# How to check if the primary key exists in my database from a textbox (windows form), c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a textbox and a button in a windows form application. 
I want to check if the primary key (persId) exists in my sql database/dataset (made with Visual studio) when I enter a number in the textbox and press the button. I dont know how to compare the text with persId from the database.

If the persId exists I want to fill two textboxes in a new form and show the persId and persName.

I am new to programming in C# so I have probably missed something. I looked at [how to check if value exists in database from textbox c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610103/how-to-check-if-value-exists-in-database-from-textbox-c-sharp) but could not find an answer.

Thanks in advance!

```
    public void searchPersId(string persId)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT persId FROM Customers  WHERE persId = @persId", conn); 
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@persId", persId);


        if (textBox1.Text = myCommand  ) //I dont know how to compare the values of textbox with myCommand..
        {
            //Show values (persId and persName) in two textBoxes in a new form. 
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The ID does not exist.");
        }


    }
```

Comment: You need to execute that command to get the result from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use the `using`-statement for everything implementing `IDisposable` like the connection to dispose unmanaged resources and to close the connection, even in case of an error.

Then you have to open the connection and to use `ExecuteReader` to get a datareader to check if there's at least one record with that ID, you can use `reader.HasRows`. You also have to select the `persName` if you want it as mentioned.

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection())
using(var myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT persId, persName FROM Customers  WHERE persId = @persId", conn))
{
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@persId", persId);
    conn.Open();
    using(var rd = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        bool personExists = rd.HasRows;
        if(personExists)
        {
            // advance the reader to the first record, presuming there is only one, otherwise use a loop while(rd.Read)
            rd.Read();
            string persName = rd.GetString(1); // second field
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The ID does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ExecuteScalar

```
public void searchPersId(string persId)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT persName FROM Customers  WHERE persId = @persId", conn);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@persId", persId);

        object personName = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(personName.ToString()))
        //if (textBox1.Text = myCommand) //I dont know how to compare the values of textbox with myCommand..
        {
            //Show values (persId and persName) in two textBoxes in a new form. 
            textBox2.Text = personName.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The ID does not exist.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you need to check for just one value to check if the record exist this is the faster and best way.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to Execute the command.

```
SqlDataReader dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);



if (dr.HasRows)
{
    // ... if it has rows then you know it match
} 
else 
{
   // ... data doesn't exists
}
```

Then you can compare the result.